# How rename pd.value_counts() index with a correspondance dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, counting

I am doing a `value_counts()` over a column of integers that represent categorical values.

I have a dict that maps the numbers to strings that correspond to the category name.

I want to find the **best** way to have the index with the corresponding name. As I am not happy with my 4 lines solution.

#### My current solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"weather": [1,2,1,3]})
df
>>>
   weather
0        1
1        2
2        1
3        3

weather_correspondance_dict = {1:"sunny", 2:"rainy", 3:"cloudy"}
```

Now how I solve the problem:

```
df_vc = df.weather.value_counts()
index = df_vc.index.map(lambda x: weather_correspondance_dict[x] )
df_vc.index = index
df_vc
>>>
sunny     2
cloudy    1
rainy     1
dtype: int64
```

#### Question

I am not happy with that solution that is very tedious, do you have a best practice for that situation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my solution :

```
>>> weather_correspondance_dict = {1:"sunny", 2:"rainy", 3:"cloudy"}
>>> df["weather"].value_counts().rename(index=weather_correspondance_dict)
    sunny     2
    cloudy    1
    rainy     1
    Name: weather, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
weathers = ['sunny', 'rainy', 'cloudy']
weathers_dict = dict(enumerate(weathers, 1))

df_vc = df['weather'].value_counts()
df_vc.index = df_vc.index.map(weathers_dict.get)
```

**Explanation**

- Use `dict` with `enumerate` to construct a dictionary mapping integers to a list of weather types.
- Use `dict.get` with `pd.Index.map`. Unlike `pd.Series.apply`, you cannot pass a dictionary directly, but you can pass a callable function instead.
- Update the index directly rather than using an intermediary variable.

---

Alternatively, you can apply your map to `weather` before using `pd.Series.value_counts`. This way, you do not need to update the index of your result.

```
df['weather'] = df['weather'].map(weathers_dict)
df_vc = df['weather'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Thx @jpp, 
I like the `df['weather'].map(weathers_dict)` solution which could then be transformed into [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-data) type. If someone  combines (or edit) both @L-- and @jpp answers that would be great !

Comment: @AdrienPacifico, I added a separate solution if you wish to use categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

#### Categorical data

You can use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) with [`pd.CategoricalIndex.rename_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.rename_categories.html):

```
s = df['weather'].value_counts()
s.index = pd.Categorical(s.index).rename_categories(weather_correspondance_dict)
```

This feature is available in Pandas v0.21+.